# Configurable products and Configurable Swatches

Tags: configuration, ce-1.9.1.0, swatches

I'm creating some attributes and attributes sets to create configurable products to use the new Configurable Swatches available in the Magento 1.9.1, but some times the configurable swatches works correctly: [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEfWX.png) and some times it does't work: [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CenXU.png). I tried to find some diference between the configurable products, and attributes that I created but I could find anything. Where should I look to find what is happening? Somebody has a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ensure that you've enabled "Cor Gloss" within System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches?

Comment: Thanks! was exactly that! I forgot to enable the new attributes! Thanks!